# How to Make a Powershell Invoke-WebRequests Script Interactively Pass Off Variables in Where-Object Strings

Tags: windows, powershell

So I have two scripts that operate within Powershell 1903 Update. 
One of the Works and one of them is Failing when I pass Variables within the Where-Object {} string.

The working Script will download the file in the Downloads directory

```
#!/bin/powershell
# ====================================================================================================
# Author: Richard Barrett
# Organization: Del Valle ISD
# Date: 12/04/2019
# Purpose: To Add an Interactive Script within Powershell for Windows Users to Download multiple Links
# ====================================================================================================

# ==============================================================================================
#         Documentation
# ==============================================================================================
# https://www.gngrninja.com/script-ninja/2016/7/8/powershell-getting-started-utilizing-the-web

# ==============================================================================================

# Interactive Authentication && Interactively Establish Target Links
# ==================================================================
# Add in Information that makes the link as an interactive question
# Add in  Authentication Question and make the authentication session interactive
#$DownloadLink = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input the link you would like to download from'
#$Authentication = Read-Host -Prompt 'Does the site you want to download from require authentication Y/n'
#$Username = Read-H
#$Password
#$Date = Get-Date


$downloadURL     = 'https://www.tukui.org/welcome.php'
$downloadRequest = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $downloadURL
$downloadRequest

# ==================================================================

# Interactively Query for Permission to Download and Save Path
# Add in Would you like to See All Download Links?

# Define the http:/ and https:/ variables
# =======================================
#$http  = echo 'http:/'
#$https = echo 'https:/'

#$downloadRequest.Links

# Add in Interactivity question where you define the parser variable based on download.
$downloadRequest.Links | Where-Object {$_ -like '*elv*' -and $_ -like '*download*'}
$elvLink = ($downloadRequest.Links | Where-Object {$_ -like '*elv*' -and $_ -like '*download*'}).href | Select -Last 1

echo "This is the suffix link, would you like to add http:// or https://?"
$elvLink

$Link = ($downloadURL + $elvLink)
$Link

# Add in Exit code for HTTP and HTTPS Based Downloads
# Write the file to the ".\Downloads\" Directory
# ====================================================
$fileName        = $Link.Substring($Link.LastIndexOf('/')+1)
$downloadRequest = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $Link
$fileContents    = $downloadRequest.Content
$downloadRequest  =  Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $Link -OutFile "C:\Users\richard.barrett\Downloads\$fileName" -PassThru
#EOF
```

So this works, and I tried to clean it up and make it more interactive. 
You can see the alterations within the following script

```
#!/bin/powershell
# ====================================================================================================
# Author: Richard Barrett
# Organization: Del Valle ISD
# Date: 12/04/2019
# Purpose: To Add an Interactive Script within Powershell for Windows Users to Download multiple Links
# ====================================================================================================

# ==============================================================================================
#         Documentation
# ==============================================================================================
# https://www.gngrninja.com/script-ninja/2016/7/8/powershell-getting-started-utilizing-the-web

# ==============================================================================================

# Interactive Authentication && Interactively Establish Target Links
# ==================================================================
# Add in Information that makes the link as an interactive question
# Add in  Authentication Question and make the authentication session interactive
echo 'Notes: You can use the following information for testing purposes for the following variables'
echo 'xxxxx: For DownloadLink use https://www.tukui.org/welcome.php'
echo 'xxxxx: For Parservariable use elv'
echo 'xxxxx: For ActionVariable use download'
echo '=================================================================================================================='
$DownloadLink           = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input the link you would like to download from for variable DownloadLink'
$Authentication         = Read-Host -Prompt 'Does the site you want to download from require authentication [Y/y]/[N/n]'
$Username               = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter in your Username for the Website you want to pull from'
$Password               = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter in the password assigned to the above entered Username'
$Date                   = Get-Date

$downloadURL            = $DownloadLink
$downloadRequest        = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $downloadURL
$downloadRequest

# Interactively Query for Permission to Download and Save Path
# Add in Would you like to See All Download Links?
#$downloadRequest.Links

# Set Parser Variable
$ParserVariable = Read-Host -Prompt 'What Parser would you like to use for variable ParserVariable?'
$ActionVariable = Read-Host -Prompt 'What action would you like to do [Download/Share] for variable ActionVariable?'
$downloadRequest.Links | Where-Object {$_ -like '*$ParserVariable*' -and $_ -like '*$ActionVariable*'}
$PackageLink    = ($downloadRequest.Links | Where-Object {$_ -like '*$ParserVariable*' -and $_ -like '*ActionVariable*'}).href | Select -Last 1

$Transport      = Read-Host -Prompt 'This is the suffix link, which transport method should be used [http:// or https://]?'
$PackageLink

$Validation     = Read-Host -Prompt 'Does the link from the above PackageLink look to be the correct format?'
$Link           = ($downloadURL + $PackageLink)
$Link

# Add in Exit code for HTTP and HTTPS Based Downloads
# Write the file to the ".\Downloads\" Directory
# ====================================================
$fileName               = $Link.Substring($Link.LastIndexOf('/')+1)
$downloadRequest        = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $Link
$fileContents           = $downloadRequest.Content
$downloadRequest        = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $Link -OutFile "C:\Users\richard.barrett\Downloads\$fileName" -PassThru
#EOF
```

The main issue I am encountering is that I want to make the parsing more interactive and pull off that from the `$downloadRequests.Links`, I have done an initial investigation and have found where the code is breaking.

Code Works:

```
$downloadRequest.Links | Where-Object {$_ -like '*elv*' -and $_ -like '*download*'}
$elvLink = ($downloadRequest.Links | Where-Object {$_ -like '*elv*' -and $_ -like '*download*'}).href | Select -Last 1

echo "This is the suffix link, would you like to add http:// or https://?"
$elvLink

$Link = ($downloadURL + $elvLink)
$Link
```

Code Fails

```
$ParserVariable = Read-Host -Prompt 'What Parser would you like to use for variable ParserVariable?'
$ActionVariable = Read-Host -Prompt 'What action would you like to do [Download/Share] for variable ActionVariable?'
$downloadRequest.Links | Where-Object {$_ -like '*$ParserVariable*' -and $_ -like '*$ActionVariable*'}
$PackageLink    = ($downloadRequest.Links | Where-Object {$_ -like '*$ParserVariable*' -and $_ -like '*ActionVariable*'}).href | Select -Last 1
```

I got the following output, while debugging the code.

```
PS C:\Users\richard.barrett\Projects\Powershell\Training\Invoke-WebRequests> $downloadRequest.Links | Where-Object {$_ -like '*'$ParserVariable'*' -and $_ -like '*'$ActionVariable'*'}                                                                   At line:1 char:52
+ ... dRequest.Links | Where-Object {$_ -like '*'$ParserVariable'*' -and $_ ...
+                                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Unexpected token '$ParserVariable'*'' in expression or statement.
At line:1 char:67
+ ... dRequest.Links | Where-Object {$_ -like '*'$ParserVariable'*' -and $_ ...
+                                                               ~~~
Unexpected token ''*'' in expression or statement.
At line:1 char:88
+ ...  {$_ -like '*'$ParserVariable'*' -and $_ -like '*'$ActionVariable'*'}
+                                                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Unexpected token '$ActionVariable'*'' in expression or statement.
At line:1 char:103
+ ...  {$_ -like '*'$ParserVariable'*' -and $_ -like '*'$ActionVariable'*'}
+                                                                      ~~~
Unexpected token ''*'' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken

PS C:\Users\richard.barrett\Projects\Powershell\Training\Invoke-WebRequests> $downloadRequest.Links | Where-Object {$_ -like '*elv*' -and $_ -like '*download*'}                                                                                          

innerHTML : &nbsp;<SPAN class=font-menu>Download (Retail)</SPAN>
innerText :  Download (Retail)
outerHTML : <A class="fa fa-download" href="/download.php?ui=elvui">&nbsp;<SPAN class=font-menu>Download (Retail)</SPAN></A>
outerText :  Download (Retail)
tagName   : A
class     : fa fa-download
href      : /download.php?ui=elvui

innerHTML : &nbsp;<SPAN class=font-menu>Changelog</SPAN>
innerText :  Changelog
outerHTML : <A class="fa  fa-file-text-o" href="/download.php?ui=elvui&amp;changelog">&nbsp;<SPAN
            class=font-menu>Changelog</SPAN></A>
outerText :  Changelog
tagName   : A
class     : fa  fa-file-text-o
href      : /download.php?ui=elvui&amp;changelog

innerHTML : Download ElvUI <SPAN class=hidden-xs>11.25</SPAN>
innerText : Download ElvUI 11.25
outerHTML : <A class="btn btn-mod btn-border-w btn-small btn-round" href="/downloads/elvui-11.25.zip">Download ElvUI <SPAN
            class=hidden-xs>11.25</SPAN> </A>
outerText : Download ElvUI 11.25
tagName   : A
class     : btn btn-mod btn-border-w btn-small btn-round
href      : /downloads/elvui-11.25.zip
```

Any Help would be greatly appreciated as I am more familiar with Linux more than anything else, currently I am trying to automate multiple download files, so I am really just using this as a template to automate some downloads onto a local server. I know I can use python, but I kind of wanted to learn a little more about Powershell at the same time.

Kindly, 
Richard

Comment: Did you try double quotation marks? Single quotation marks do not allow variables. Also, I am not sure whether `-like` is the correct operator for regex. I would suggest to use `-match`. EDIT: I just saw that only the asterisk character is in single quotation marks. I would not expect that to work. Try `$_ -match "*$ParserVariable*"`.

Comment: This is correct, +1 to @Alex_P and a wildcard is a subset of regex so it'll work on `-match`. You'll get slightly better performance on `-like` compared to `-match` and string methods like `.contains('some_string') is best for performance.

Comment: I will give it a shot today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @Alex_P said in his comment, using single quotation will make it a string literal. Use double quotation so that PowerShell will use the variables.

Also, if you're sure that you will use a `*` wildcard, then it is recommended to use `-like` since it is mostly used for wildcard comparisons. Otherwise, use `-match` for regular expressions.

```
$ParserVariable = Read-Host -Prompt "What Parser would you like to use for variable ParserVariable?"
$ActionVariable = Read-Host -Prompt "What action would you like to do [Download/Share] for variable ActionVariable?"
$downloadRequest.Links | Where-Object {$_ -like "*$ParserVariable*" -and $_ -like "*$ActionVariable*"}
$PackageLink    = ($downloadRequest.Links | Where-Object {$_ -like "*$ParserVariable*" -and $_ -like "*ActionVariable*"}).href | Select -Last 1
```

Also, a wildcard is a subset of regex so it'll work on `-match`. You'll get slightly better performance on `-like` compared to `-match` and string methods like `.contains('some_string')` is best for performance. The caveat is, the `.contains()` method will only return a boolean value.

Comment: I will give it a shot today.

Comment: It worked, however I am still seeing some issues with the code, which I knew would happen as I am not filtering somewhere correctly for the actual file. My end goal is to see all links available on the website, have it show them to you, you select which one you want, and then proceed to download it. Other than that I got the `Welcome.php` file. So it definitely works on downloading information. Now I just need to add in some if and while statements and add some more interactivity to get what I want.

Comment: That's good to hear. I'm glad you got it to work. If you have any more issues, you can ask another question when you're stuck and we'll try to help you the best we can!

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate it.